# SQL multiple table nested group by using Ruby on Rails Active Record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

**Models:**

A `survey` has `survey_answers` which each have an `answer` and a  `question`

A `question` belongs to a `category`.

**Example:**

`Survey_answer` has `survey_id` and `answer_id` and `question_id`

`question` has `category_id`

I am using `Ruby on Rails` with `Active Record`

Using `SQL`, and starting with a survey, how can I group as following:

`{ category => questions => answers }`

Example output:

```
{[
  category_one_record, 
    [question_1,[answer_1, answer_2]],
    [question_2,[answer_3, answer_4]],
  category_two_record, 
    [question_3,[answer_5, answer_6]],
    [question_4,[answer_7, answer_8]],
  category_three_record,
    ...
]}
```

I understand how to do a group but I don't understand how to do a nested grouping with `SQL`

Comment: Well, that depends on the shape of the output you want.  Show us an example result set and we can work towards that for you.

Comment: @MatBailie I just gave a sample result

Comment: You want the results as JSON?

Comment: Please provide https://dbfiddle.uk
 sample data and desired resultset.

Comment: @MatBailie sure or whatever I can work with. I'm using Active Record with Ruby on Rails this is usually the format that is returned I believe.

Comment: No, normally SQL doesn't return nested structures like that at all.  SQL is tabular.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you're thinking about this in a non-SQL manner.

SQL is tabular, and when returning this kind of information it is normal to accept the repetition rather than look to generate a nested data structure (such as can be done with JSON, XML, etc).

You don't ***appear*** to want any actual aggregation *(what `GROUP BY` is for)*.  Instead you're referring to one way of keeping related records next to each other.

The would simply be joining the data and then ordering it.

You're original post isn't clear on the table structures, so this is a very rough example of what I mean...

```
SELECT
  survey.name   AS survey_name,
  category.name AS category_name,
  question.text AS question_text,
  answer.text   AS answer_text
FROM
  survey
INNER JOIN
  question
    ON question.survey_id = survey.id
INNER JOIN
  category
    ON category.id = question.category_id
INNER JOIN
  answer
    ON answer.question_id = question.id
ORDER BY
  survey.name,
  category.name,
  question.text,
  answer.text
```

Such a query might then return a record set that looks like the following...

```
 survey_name | category_name | question_text | answer_text
-------------+---------------+---------------+-------------
 survey_1    | category_1    | question_1    | answer_1
 survey_1    | category_1    | question_1    | answer_2
 survey_1    | category_1    | question_2    | answer_3
 survey_1    | category_1    | question_2    | answer_4
 survey_1    | category_2    | question_3    | answer_5
```

Tabular.  Not nested.

Answer (score 0):

If you have natural joins available you can almost always pair table up with it even if you don't know how it works, like this:

```
select * from Survey_answer 
               natural join question 
               natural join category 
               where category_id = 1
```

If you don't have this option available you need to specify the joining points and if it's right, left or inner for example:

```
select * from Survey_answer 
               inner join question on Survey_answer.answer_id like  question.answer_id
               where Survey_answer.category_id = 1
```

You may learn more about this here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp